# Local variable in Ruby on Rails is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, web-applications, devise

I am currently following a [recipe box](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhdzE1yNs-0) tutorial on youtube.
When I open the rails console and type

```
@recipe = current_user.recipes.build
```

I got the following error:

```bash
NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for main:Object
from (irb):3
from /Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
from /Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
from /Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
from /Users/matthiascordes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:9:in `require'
from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

Does anybody has an idea what is wrong and how I can solve this problem?
I am using the devise gem for my user model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can not access `current_user` inside your rails console,so try

```
user = User.find(your_user_id)
user.recipes.build
```

Comment: All right, I will try that. Where exactly do I have to add these lines?

Comment: inside your rails console, because you're trying to access current_user inside console, for that you need a user to perform some operations, so for example you can do, `user = User.find(id)`, now you have a user to perform something

Answer (score 1):

**current_user** is a variable provided by one of the before_filters of devise, therefore, outside a controller you don't have access to it, if you still want to be in that context, you can use gem [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) and drop a **byebug** inside your code, or a **debugger** and the execution will stop and you will be in the scope you need, to test all you are required, otherwise, plain in **rails c**, you will need to fetch the user the old way, with a query

```ruby
User.find(user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `current_user` in rails console . 
If you want the user variable, then search it like

```
user = User.find(some_id)
```

& then use it like `user.recipes.build`
you can also create the user from rails console like `user = User.create(user parameters)` & then use it building receipies